# How to assert json path value is greater than value?

Tags: json, spring, testing, jsonpath, hamcrest

Given the following JSON that is returned from a REST call:

```
{"Statistik Eintraege":
[{"Wert":"1","Anzahl":41},
{"Wert":"","Anzahl":482},
{"Wert":"-3","Anzahl":1},
{"Wert":"-1","Anzahl":3},
{"Wert":"-2","Anzahl":3}],
"Statistik Typ":"BlahStatistik"}
```

... I want to verify that'Anzahl' of Wert='' is greater than 400 (is in this example: 482).

What I tried in my java integration test is:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl", greaterThan(400)));

The exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (net.minidev.json.JSONArray is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

    at org.hamcrest.comparator.ComparatorMatcherBuilder$1.compare(ComparatorMatcherBuilder.java:22)
    at org.hamcrest.comparator.ComparatorMatcherBuilder$ComparatorMatcher.describeMismatchSafely(ComparatorMatcherBuilder.java:86)
    at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.describeMismatch(TypeSafeMatcher.java:82)
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:18)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$0(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at
```

What else could I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JsonPath operator `[?(<expression>)]` selects all elements matching the given expression. Therefore, the result is a json array.

In the example `[?(@.Wert == '')]` matches all json nodes with the field `Wert` having an empty value. Your json sample has only single item matching the predicate, but in general there could be multiple. To fix you have either to define a more specific expression matching only a single element or to adjust the matcher to work on a collection.

Matching collection:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl", everyItem(greaterThan(400))))
```